# What should I do in argument "i:String.index"

Tags: swift

the resultByuser is a SKLabelNode and it could be only include number, here below I want to let user delete the number one by one if they want, but don't know what to do in argument.The "removeAll" function is work but not perfectly because I don't want to remove all number.

[image]

```
    func deleteNumber(){
//        resultByUser.text.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        resultByUser.text.removeAtIndex(i: String.Index)
    }
```

Comment: From what you're saying, I'm assuming that you want to remove the end number, you can use `resultByUser.text.removeAtIndex(result.text.endIndex)`.

Comment: @ILikeTau Wow, ".text.startIndex" is what I need, many thanks:)